# flutter how to read get response from serial port rs232 in flutter windows app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

i'm using serial_port_win32 0.5.2, RS232, for recipe printer, windows 10.

port.writeBytesFromUint8List();

are working well however i try to get response for status of printer like

```
    port.readBytesOnListen(8, (value)  {
      print('printer value:  $value');
    });

    port.writeBytesFromUint8List(Uint8List.fromList([0x1B, 0x48]));
```

or

```
    port.readOnListenFunction = (value){
      print('printer value: $value');
    };
    port.writeBytesFromUint8List(Uint8List.fromList([0x1B, 0x48]));
```

or

```
List<int> response = await _printerPort.readBytesOnce(8);
    port.writeBytesFromUint8List(Uint8List.fromList([0x1B, 0x48]));
    print('readBytesOnce : $response');
```

but theres no any print.

i already tried to use other library but it was worse.

Comment: Any luck in solving this issue? @jichang